# Как подключить ключ в json?

Tags: json

Есть файл data.json c код ключом "navigation".

Как подключить второй ключ, к примеру, `"sub_navigation"`?

```
{
  "navigation": "[ <ul> 
    <li>\ <a href=\"/catalog/">Женщинам</a>                                                        
}
```

Comment: @Dmitry_4333, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

ээ.

```
$array = json_decode(file_get_content("data.json"), true);
$array["sub_navigation"] = array(что-то про суб-навигацию);
$json = json_encode($array);
$fh = fopen("data.json","w");
fwrite($fh, $json, strlen($json));
fclose($fh);
```

Как-то так.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос не очень понятен, вы это имеете в виду?

```
{
  "navigation":"<h1>keyOne</h1>",
  "sub_navigation":"<h1>keyTwo</h1>"
}
```